# Sentry limit notifications to certain users

Tags: python, sentry

Can I give a user access to a sentry project but not send him all the emails?

Sometimes I want to forward the error message to our mobile developers, so they can see the parameters, but they don't need to get all the other reports.

Answer (score 0):

I found it - found even two different ways:

1. I can make projects public (under project settings) so everyone (with a sentry account) can access it.
2. I can give a users access to a project and that user has to opt-out of emails by going to his Account (top right) and then notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this is to make the organization "open membership". Members can then choose to join or leave teams, and opt-out of project-specific notifications when they want.